# flutter app for windows, has to run as admin, or error: 0xc0000022

Tags: flutter, flutter-windows

i just start to use flutter, and finally make the flutter env worked.
but i have a problem now, if i do: flutter build windows --release --split-debug-info=xxx
it just failed(succeed in debug mode):

```
H:\Tools\VisualStudio\VS\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(248,5):  

**error MSB8066:**

“H:\Saves\FlutterSaves\samples-main\animations\build\windows\CMakeFiles\c0432f05eb41a37864438fbb4d88b349\flutter_windows.dll.rule;H:\Saves\FlutterSaves\samples-main\animations\build\windows\CMakeFiles\7c76642dc092b463cde84841de670281\flutter_assemble.rule;H:\Saves\FlutterSaves\samples-main\animations\windows\flutter\CMakeLists.txt”的自定义生成已退出 
，代码为 1。
[H:\Saves\FlutterSaves\samples-main\animations\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
```

thats a small problem. i found that build release first(faild though) and then build debug, the exe file in release folder just worked.(wtf???)
but the release version exe must run as admin, or it ran faied ,error code:0xc0000022.(debug mode doesnt have this problem.)

i had searched in google, discord, github and here. but cant resolve my problem.
i wanna the app could run without admin limit.T T

Comment: Post the (relevant) code where this happens and the full error message you get.

Comment: it's just a start project(counter),  and i sent the exe file to my friend. he runs without any error. so i think there may be something wrong with my system.